# Meteorjs React “Uncaught Error: Cannot find module ‘/imports/ui/app’”

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router

I have an app currently deployed on the free tier on Meteor Cloud, for testing purposes.

The app works fine on localhost, but upon deploying it to the server, the app shows a blank page, even though it is successfully deployed. There is an error in the console that says:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '/imports/ui/app'
```

This app uses react-router 6. Here is the `main.js` excerpt of the corresponding line:

```
...
import App from '/imports/ui/app';   //the line that is causing headache
import Dashboard from '/imports/ui/dashboard';
...

Meteor.startup(() => {
  
  Tracker.autorun(() => {
    const routes = (
      <>
      <Router>
        <CurrentUserProfileProvider>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<App />}/>
            <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes/>}>
              <Route path='/verify' element={<React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}> <Verify/> </React.Suspense>} />
              <Route path='/dashboard' element={<React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}> <Dashboard /> </React.Suspense>} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </CurrentUserProfileProvider>
      </Router>
      </>
    );
    render(routes, document.getElementById('target'));
  });
});
```

App.js

```
    const App = () => {
    ...
       return (
       //some jsx here
       )
    }
   export default App;
```

I’ve tried several forms of path e.g. "../imports/ui/app" and ../imports/ui/app.js but still on the deployed server, the same error occurs. Has anybody encountered a similar problem? Or is there something that I missed here? I’m new to React Router 6 and still trying to figure it out. Appreciate any kind of help I can get here.

Comment: Hello, will need a little bit more information here:

1. Location of your main.js

2. Exact name of the file - capital cases does matter after deploy since deploys are on Linux, that may be a problem - also, you have to include file extension in your case ".js"

3. Also exact path of "app.js" is it "[MeteorProjectFolder]/imports/..."

Comment: If dev. env. works fine, maybe you can try to do a production build on localhost and look closely into browser's minified meteor files: "$ meteor run --production" https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-run-vs-meteor-run-production

Answer (score 0):

How is your `App` component defined? Shouldn't the import be like this:

```
import { App } from '/imports/ui/App';
```

Notice the curly brackets wrapping the `App`.

Comment: it's a normal react functional component. i've added the App.js file structure for clarity.